# How to make "user-resizable modal dialog" within Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I tried `JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JFrame`, but none of them works exactly.

- `JWindow`: Can set parent window, but can't do modal mode
- `JDialog`: Can set parent window and open modal mode, but user cannot resize window.
- `JFrame`: User can resize window, but cannot set parent window, nor modal mode.

Is there some way to open modal dialog that user can resize (or maximize) window?

EDIT: I just found setResizable() thanks to @kiheru. However, is there some way to "maximize" that window? Using `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` doesn't sufficient since the dialog overlaps task bar.

Comment: Modal JDialogs are resizable. Show us your code.

Comment: You can use `setResizable()` with `JDialog`.

Comment: A modal full-screen dialog isn't very standard. Why don't you use a CardLayout and display the content of your dialog as the body of the main frame, which can be maximized.

Comment: I think it might be good idea following idea of @jb-nizet. Thanks for suggestion.